# modal popup in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

i am using model popup in asp.net on this linkbutton

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"  CssClass="addProduct-disable" Enabled ="false" Text="Assign Filter Criteria"  CausesValidation="true"                    ></asp:LinkButton>
```

when i click a button in popup the event is getting fired but the asp panel and label are not getting displayed

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" class="style3" align="center">
                        Assign Filtering Criteria
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                        &nbsp;
                        <asp:Label ID="lblSuccess" runat="server" Text="" ></asp:Label>    

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="logText" width="30%">
                        Filter:
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgFilter" runat="server" ImageUrl="../images/helpIcon.png"
                            border="0" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="return showHelp('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pnlFilterHelp');" />
                        <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mdlFilter" runat="server" TargetControlID="imgFilter"
                            PopupControlID="pnlFilterHelp" DropShadow="false" CancelControlID="lnkFilterCancel"
                            X="410" Y="200" />
                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlFilterHelp" runat="server" Height="70px" Width="170px" Style="display: none;">
                            <asp:Panel ID="pnlFilterOuter" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup2" Height="100px"
                                Width="180px" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" BackColor="#FFFCF9">
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="90%">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding-top: 15px; padding-left: 5px;">
                                            <table cellpadding="0" align="center" cellspacing="0" width="100%" height="40px">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="style8">
                                                        Set Filter Criteria so that customer can easily search product.
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            &nbsp;
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="padding-left: 20px;">
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkFilterCancel" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="gridPagerlink"
                                                ForeColor="Black">Close <b>X</b></asp:LinkButton>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </td>
                    <td width="4px">
                    </td>
                    <td class="logBox">
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="filter" runat="server">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="drpFilter" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpFilter_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                    Width="150px">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="logText">
                        Filter Option:
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgFilterOption" runat="server" ImageUrl="../images/helpIcon.png"
                            border="0" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="return showHelp('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pnlFilterOption');" />
                        <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mdlFilterOption" runat="server" TargetControlID="imgFilterOption"
                            PopupControlID="pnlFilterOption" DropShadow="false" CancelControlID="lnkFilterOptionCancel"
                            X="410" Y="220" />
                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlFilterOption" runat="server" Height="70px" Width="170px" Style="display: none;">
                            <asp:Panel ID="pnlFilterOptionOuter" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup2" Height="300px"
                                Width="580px" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" BackColor="#FFFCF9">
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="90%">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding-top: 15px; padding-left: 5px;">
                                            <table cellpadding="0" align="center" cellspacing="0" width="100%" height="40px">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="style8">
                                                        Set Filter Criteria Option so that customer can easily search product.
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            &nbsp;
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="padding-left: 20px;">
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkFilterOptionCancel" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="gridPagerlink"
                                                ForeColor="Black">Close <b>X</b></asp:LinkButton>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </td>
                    <td width="4px">
                    </td>
                    <td class="logBox">
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="drpFilterOption" runat="server" Width="150px" Enabled="false">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="logText">
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td width="4px">
                    </td>
                    <td class="logBox">
                        &nbsp;
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="cancel" runat="server">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Style="font-weight: 700; text-align: right"
                                    Text="Add" CssClass="Login-btn" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" />
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>

            </td> </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" colspan="3">
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlAddFilter" runat="server" style="display:none">
                        <table id="list">
                        </table>
                        <div id="pager" style="text-align: center;">
                        </div>
                        <br />
                      </asp:Panel>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

            </tr>
            </table>
```

event is

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pnlAddFilter.Style.Add("display", "block");
        //pnlAddFilter.Visible = true;
        DataTable dtFilter = new DataTable();
        dtFilter.Columns.Add("FOId");
        dtFilter.Columns.Add("Filtername");
        dtFilter.Columns.Add("FilterOption");
        DataRow drFilter;
        if (Session["Filter"] != null)
        {
            dtFilter = (DataTable)Session["Filter"];
        }

        drFilter = dtFilter.NewRow();
        drFilter["FOId"] = drpFilterOption.SelectedValue;
        drFilter["Filtername"] = drpFilter.SelectedItem.Text;
        drFilter["FilterOption"] = drpFilterOption.SelectedItem.Text;
        dtFilter.Rows.Add(drFilter);
        Session["Filter"] = dtFilter;
        btnAdd.Enabled = false;
        if (Session["Filter"] == null)
        {
          //  pnlAddFilter.Visible = false;
            pnlAddFilter.Style.Add("display", "none");
        }
        else
        {
            pnlAddFilter.Style.Add("display", "block");
          //  pnlAddFilter.Visible = true;
        }
        lblSuccess.Visible = true;
        lblSuccess.Text = AppHardcodeValue.strAddFilterProduct; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the modal popup doesn't support dynamically rendered data very well.  I'm thinking you probably need to put your modal content inside of an update panel in order to be able to use the server side code to update the label.